# Angular convert multiple Files into base64 string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, base64, angular6

I try to convert multiple files into multiple base64 strings.
But somehow my reader only spits out the same file over and over again. Anyone an Idea how to fix it?

```js
handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];

    for (let item of files) {
      this.postData.name = item.name;
      this.postData.type = item.type;
      var reader = new FileReader();


      reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);

      reader.readAsBinaryString(item);
    }

  }


  _handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt, item) {
    var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
    this.base64textString = btoa(binaryString);
    this.postData.base64 = this.base64textString;
    this.saveToDB();
    this.image = "data:image;base64, ";


  }
```

Comment: I played around with this in stackblitz, hard to replicate completely, but I am curious... have you tried passing the arguments to _handleReaderLoaded() instead of bind(this) to see if there is a difference in behavior? or possibly pass the reader into the function and use reader.result?

Comment: why use base64?